# How i can use full outer join in symfony2 by query builder?

Tags: symfony, dql, query-builder, full-outer-join

I  want to use full outer join by queryBuilder function. for left join i used this code:

```
$qb = $qb->select('person')
        ->from('S118EbrahimiBundle:PersonEntity', 'person')
        ->leftJoin('person.PhoneEntities', 'phone');
```

but i dont know how i can perform full outer join!

Comment: what do you want , persons without phones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see into [doctrine2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#helper-methods), it isn't possible to perform an outerjoin (with `query builder` help, obviously).
Two only operation you can perform are `leftJoin` and `innerJoin`

I suppose that you have to write it (as a plain query, not through `query builder`)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible and you should use nested left join!